# Jquery effect function call not working in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a code which displays **congradulations** and displays **stars** popping out when body loads in a blue screen for for a timeout of 4000

when body loads it calls a function **animatecongrat()** which has two functions in it given below

The text congradulations is animated in function **animatetext()**, and stars animated in **animateblobs()**

**My problem is text congradulation is animated and bluescreen appears for a timeout of 4000 but stars ( var numberOfStars = 20; in blob) are not appearing and animated in blue screen.**

How to solve this? How do i achieve this effect?

```js
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.18.0/TweenMax.min.js'></script>
    <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.2/underscore-min.js'></script>

<script>
var timeOut;

function animateCongrat() 
{
 debugger;
  $('.congrats').show();
  clearTimeout(timeOut);
  addBlueBody();
  reset();
  var numberOfStars = 20;

  for (var i = 0; i < numberOfStars; i++) {
    $('.congrats').append('<div class="blob fa fa-star ' + i + '"></div>');
  }

  animateText();
  animateBlobs();
  hideCongratAndBlueBody();
}

function addBlueBody() {
  $('body').addClass('bodyblue');
 $('#2').hide(); 
 $('.hiddenimage').show();
}

function hideCongratAndBlueBody() {
    timeOut = setTimeout(() => {
    $('.congrats').hide();
    $('body').removeClass('bodyblue');  
  }, 4000);
}

function reset() {
  $.each($('.blob'), function(i) {
    TweenMax.set($(this), {
      x: 0,
      y: 0,
      opacity: 1
    });
  });

  TweenMax.set($('h1'), {
    scale: 1,
    opacity: 1,
    rotation: 0
  });
}

function animateText() {
  TweenMax.from($('h1'), 0.8, {
    scale: 0.4,
    opacity: 0,
    rotation: 15,
    ease: Back.easeOut.config(4),
  });
}

function animateBlobs() {
 debugger;

  var xSeed = _.random(500, 500);
  debugger;
  var ySeed = _.random(300, 300);

  $.each($('.blob'), function(i) {
    var $blob = $(this);
    var speed = _.random(1, 5);
    var rotation = _.random(5, 100);
    var scale = _.random(0.8, 1.5);
    var x = _.random(-xSeed, xSeed);
    var y = _.random(-ySeed, ySeed);

    TweenMax.to($blob, speed, {
      x: x,
      y: y,
      ease: Power1.easeOut,
      opacity: 0,
      rotation: rotation,
      scale: scale,
      onStartParams: [$blob],
      onStart: function($element) {
        $element.css('display', 'block');
      },
      onCompleteParams: [$blob],
      onComplete: function($element) {
        $element.css('display', 'none');
      }
    });
  });
}
```

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Sigmar One';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Sigmar One Regular'), local('SigmarOne-Regular'), url(https: //fonts.gstatic.com/s/sigmarone/v8/co3DmWZ8kjZuErj9Ta3do6Tpow.ttf) format('truetype');
}

@import url(https: //fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Sigmar+One);
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dashed {
 border: 2px dashed #999 !important;
}
.bodyblue {
  background: #3da1d1;
  color: #fff;
  width: 0.3vw;
  height: 0.5vh;
}

.congrats {
  position: absolute;
  top: 140px;
  width: 550px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 20px 10px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: none;
}

h1 {
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-family: 'Sigmar One', cursive;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 2;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top:-10.5vh;
  left: 0.3vw;
}


.blob {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  color: #ffcc00;
  position: absolute;
  top: 45%;
  left: 45%;
  z-index: 1;
  font-size: 30px;
  display: none;
}



.heading{
margin-left:20%;
margin-right:20%;
margin-top:-2%;
}

.text {
    padding: 20px;
    margin:7 px;
    margin-top:10px;
    color:white;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-align:center;
}

body{
    background-image:
    background-size: 100vw 100vh;
}

.next{
margin-right:50%;
margin-left:50%;
margin-bottom:10%;
float:right;
}

ul{
-moz-border-radius: 50%;
-webkit-border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body onload="animateCongrat();">
<div class="congrats"> 
  <h1>Congratulations!</h1>
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: You are loading the jQuery library 4 times, in different versions. You should never load it more than once. Not sure if that's the cause of the problem tho, the snippet functionality is currently down on SO so I'm not able to see your code running.

Comment: @victoria-ruiz  Thanks for reply,                if i use min.js only does it gives functions of tweenmax also?  which is that library which contains all these?

Comment: I don't see TweenMax requiring jQuery at all, but you are using some jQuery functionality in your code. You need to keep calling one version of jQuery (probably the latest), and the JS for TweenMax.